# Why is my HQL query eager loading lazy associations?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to improve performance of my HQL query, and I'm stumped. My OneToOne associations on the Adjuster, ZipCode, and EagleUsers objects are all marked as FetchType.LAZY, but nonetheless they're getting immediately pulled from the database when I use this query.

```
session.createQuery(
            "FROM Adjuster a, ZipCode z, EagleUsers e WHERE a.eagleUsersByUserId = e.userId AND a.adjusterContact.zipCode = z.zip AND a.active = true AND a.isRecordDeleted = false"
            ).setMaxResults(1).list();
```

Why is it doing that?

SQL Output:

```
Hibernate: select top 1 adjuster0_.AdjusterId as Adjuster1_2_0_, zipcode1_.ZipId as ZipId1_163_1_, eagleusers2_.UserId as UserId1_91_2_, adjuster0_.Active as Active2_2_0_, adjuster0_.AutoAssign as AutoAssi3_2_0_, adjuster0_.SupervisorId as Supervis6_2_0_, adjuster0_.UserId as UserId7_2_0_, adjuster0_.IsRecordDeleted as IsRecord4_2_0_, adjuster0_.IsW2 as IsW5_2_0_, zipcode1_.Areacode as Areacode2_163_1_, zipcode1_.City as City3_163_1_, zipcode1_.County as County4_163_1_, zipcode1_.DST as DST5_163_1_, zipcode1_.Latitude as Latitude6_163_1_, zipcode1_.Longitude as Longitud7_163_1_, zipcode1_.State as State8_163_1_, zipcode1_.Timezone as Timezone9_163_1_, zipcode1_.TimezoneOffset as Timezon10_163_1_, zipcode1_.Zip as Zip11_163_1_, eagleusers2_.FirstName as FirstNam2_91_2_, eagleusers2_.IsRecordDeleted as IsRecord3_91_2_, eagleusers2_.LastName as LastName4_91_2_, eagleusers2_.SubRoleId as SubRoleI5_91_2_ from eagle_prd.dbo.Adjuster adjuster0_ cross join eagle_prd.dbo.ZipCode zipcode1_ cross join eagle_prd.dbo.EagleUsers eagleusers2_ cross join eagle_prd.dbo.AdjusterContact adjusterco3_ where adjuster0_.AdjusterId=adjusterco3_.AdjusterId and adjuster0_.UserId=eagleusers2_.UserId and adjusterco3_.ZipCode=zipcode1_.Zip and adjuster0_.Active=1 and adjuster0_.IsRecordDeleted=0
Hibernate: select adjusterau0_.AdjusterId as Adjuster1_3_0_, adjusterau0_.CurrentWorkZipCode as CurrentW2_3_0_, adjusterau0_.ExcludeHomeZip as ExcludeH3_3_0_, adjusterau0_.HomeZipCode1 as HomeZipC4_3_0_, adjusterau0_.HomeZipCode2 as HomeZipC5_3_0_, adjusterau0_.IsRecordDeleted as IsRecord6_3_0_, adjusterau0_.MaxOneDayClaims as MaxOneDa7_3_0_, adjusterau0_.MaxOneWeekClaims as MaxOneWe8_3_0_, adjusterau0_.MaxTwoDayClaims as MaxTwoDa9_3_0_, adjusterau0_.VacationEnd as Vacatio10_3_0_, adjusterau0_.VacationStart as Vacatio11_3_0_, adjusterau0_.WebAssignments as WebAssi12_3_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.AdjusterAutoAssign adjusterau0_ where adjusterau0_.AdjusterId=?
Hibernate: select adjusterco0_.AdjusterId as Adjuster1_7_0_, adjusterco0_.CarAllowance as CarAllow2_7_0_, adjusterco0_.IsRecordDeleted as IsRecord3_7_0_, adjusterco0_.PhoneAllowance as PhoneAll4_7_0_, adjusterco0_.PhotoPercentage as PhotoPer5_7_0_, adjusterco0_.SeviceFeePercentage as SeviceFe6_7_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.AdjusterCompensation adjusterco0_ where adjusterco0_.AdjusterId=?
Hibernate: select adjusterco0_.AdjusterId as Adjuster1_8_0_, adjusterco0_.City as City2_8_0_, adjusterco0_.Fax as Fax3_8_0_, adjusterco0_.IsRecordDeleted as IsRecord4_8_0_, adjusterco0_.Mobile as Mobile5_8_0_, adjusterco0_.Phone as Phone6_8_0_, adjusterco0_.PhoneExt as PhoneExt7_8_0_, adjusterco0_.State as State8_8_0_, adjusterco0_.Street1 as Street9_8_0_, adjusterco0_.Street2 as Street10_8_0_, adjusterco0_.ZipCode as ZipCode11_8_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.AdjusterContact adjusterco0_ where adjusterco0_.AdjusterId=?
Hibernate: select aspnetuser0_.UserId as UserId1_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.ApplicationId as Applicat7_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.IsAnonymous as IsAnonym2_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.LastActivityDate as LastActi3_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.LoweredUserName as LoweredU4_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.MobileAlias as MobileAl5_171_0_, aspnetuser0_.UserName as UserName6_171_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.aspnet_Users aspnetuser0_ where aspnetuser0_.UserId=?
Hibernate: select aspnetmemb0_.UserId as UserId1_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.ApplicationId as Applica21_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.Comment as Comment2_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.CreateDate as CreateDa3_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.Email as Email4_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount as FailedPa5_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart as FailedPa6_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.FailedPasswordAttemptCount as FailedPa7_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart as FailedPa8_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.IsApproved as IsApprov9_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.IsLockedOut as IsLocke10_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.LastLockoutDate as LastLoc11_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.LastLoginDate as LastLog12_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.LastPasswordChangedDate as LastPas13_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.LoweredEmail as Lowered14_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.MobilePIN as MobileP15_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.Password as Passwor16_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.PasswordAnswer as Passwor17_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.PasswordFormat as Passwor18_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.PasswordQuestion as Passwor19_167_0_, aspnetmemb0_.PasswordSalt as Passwor20_167_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.aspnet_Membership aspnetmemb0_ where aspnetmemb0_.UserId=?
Hibernate: select aspnetprof0_.UserId as UserId1_168_0_, aspnetprof0_.LastUpdatedDate as LastUpda2_168_0_, aspnetprof0_.PropertyNames as Property3_168_0_, aspnetprof0_.PropertyValuesBinary as Property4_168_0_, aspnetprof0_.PropertyValuesString as Property5_168_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.aspnet_Profile aspnetprof0_ where aspnetprof0_.UserId=?
Hibernate: select eagleuseri0_.UserId as UserId1_90_0_, eagleuseri0_.MobilePhone as MobilePh2_90_0_, eagleuseri0_.OfficePhone as OfficePh3_90_0_ from eagle_prd.dbo.EagleUserInfo eagleuseri0_ where eagleuseri0_.UserId=?
```

Comment: How else can hibernate know what Adjuster, ZipCode and EagleUsers it needs to query? Can you post the querylog and point out what is not logical in your opinion?

Comment: @MartijnBurger I'm expecting it to grab Adjuster, ZipCode, and EagleUsers--what I'm not expecting it to do is to grab every child object of those, nor every child object of the child objects etc.

Comment: I guess it is the list() method that is doing that. What happens when you leave it off. BTW: The list() method is not part of the Query interface, where does it come from? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: It is a hibernate specific method: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hibernate Query.list() function fetches the complete object, including it's references as it creates a list that is detached from the hibernate scope.

Comment: Then how do I query the database without pulling down the whole object graph?

Comment: That is a completely different question. :)